# can't install intel HAMX

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator

I just started with flutter and I wanted to run the emulator but I have a problem that I cannot install intel HAXM because every time I try I get the error on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a23Q0.png)
(the link in there didn't help)

how can I install it?

Comment: please enable `virtualization` from bios

Answer (score 0):

please try to install HAXM from the given link
https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases

Answer (score 0):

if you are an HP user then Follow these steps you can easily install HAXM.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kevTrjdTlgA&ab_channel=TipsByAnil

Try this.
for me, it worked.